# Start a bash session from python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to drop into a shell for a ctf competition I am working on. I am not allowed to use `pwntools` for this. I want to achieve something like following from python:

```py
import os
os.system("/bin/bash &")
print("hello world")                 # assume I am writing to a file
os.system("fg")                      # does not work (but assume resuming shell /bin/bash)
```

I can't use subprocess since I need to drop into a shell. Not communicate back and forth with the bash process which would run in the background. Is there an easy way to approach this?

Comment: What about using bash's `echo` to print. `os.system("/bin/bash & echo 'hello world' & fg")`?

Comment: Sounds like an easier way would be to use a `while` loop to mock a shell session with `input`, and then send each command to `subprocess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `subprocess` module instead. `fg` is a shell built-in command that only works with job control in the shell itself.

```
import subprocess


p = subprocess.Popen(["bash"])
print('hello world')
p.wait()
```